# How can I set the value of an input the same as the value of the radio selected?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

```js
var value = $(".radioc").attr("value");

$("input[name=user-type]").change(function() {
  $(".input-txt-choose").val(value).toggle(this.value === value);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" class="radioc" name="user-type" value="Brand">Brand
<input type="radio" class="radioc" name="user-type" value="Store">Store
<input type="text" class="input-txt-choose" value="">
```

Show the **value** (`.radioc`) in the **input** (`.input-txt-choose`), when I select the **radio** (`.radioc`)

When I select the option "Store", **input** (`.input-txt-choose`) hides.

this is my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/behrouzbash/jk6p3dhu/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("input[name=user-type]").change(function(){
 $(".input-txt-choose").val($(this).val());
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The input will disappear because the function `.toggle()` is used to hide/show an element by jquery.

[jquery toggle](https://api.jquery.com/toggle/)

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the radio hide because of the toggle implemented, so please use the below code this will solve your purpose.

```
$(document).on("click", ".radioc", function () {
 $(".input-txt-choose").val($('.radioc:checked').val());
})
```